# How to provide a true alias key sequence in emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-binding

I would like in Emacs a key sequence FOO to be an true alias for a sequence BAR. Whenever FOO is entered it should perform the same action as entering BAR does.

I cannot use something like:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "FOO") (key-binding (kbd "BAR")))
```

That binds FOO to the current action for BAR 
. If BAR will be later remapped or overwritten or hidden by a minor mode, that will not be reflected by FOO.

I tried to workaround that using:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "FOO") 
  (lambda ()
   (interactive)
   (key-binding (kbd "BAR")))
```

But that still is not a true alias. The interactive spec for the lambda is not the same as for the action that BAR is bound to. I suppose I can address that using `(interactive (advice-eval-interactive ...))`, but it seems rater complex for something that sounds like a basic functionality.

So perhaps I missed some Emacs API for doing key aliasing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "FOO") (kbd "BAR"))
```